# vimeo-player jumps to 00:00 after setting its current time

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I want to embed buttons on a website that controll a vimeo player:

**Button A:**  player.loadVideo(Video A) & player.setCurrtenTime(15) & player.play()

**Button B:**  player.loadVideo(Video B) & player.setCurrentTime(22) & player.play()

- loading the Video works. (Video is loaded)
- setting the Current Time works. (Time and Progress Bar show the wantet result for a short time)
- **But:** As soon the video is played, the time jumps back to 00:00.

The problem also occurs, when the player is startet manually. Until I click the play button in the embedded vimeo player the players time and progress bar display the wanted time.

This is my javascript:

```
const playVideo = async (id, time) => {
   try {
     await player.loadVideo(id);
     await player.setCurrentTime(time);
     await player.play();
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
}
```

Here is a link to the vimeo player API:
https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/blob/master/README.md#table-of-contents

I cannot figure out what goes wrong here and would be happy if someone knows how to solve this problem.

S W

Comment: How is `playVideo` called?

Comment: I'm calling it like this:
<button onclick="playVideo(25068260,10)">Play</button>